# ¿Por qué no entra en la condición si el valor es correcto?

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, condiciones, matriz

Primero que nada, disculpen por no aclarar bien la pregunta.

Estoy haciendo ejercicios con javascript de hace poco y estoy con uno, en particular, que es un poco complejo.

El ejercicio consiste en crear una función a la que se le pasa un array simple y otro multidimensional (creo que se dice así) y del multidimensional (de tres valores) se tendría que hacer lo siguiente:

- El índice 0 es el primer índice del array simple.
- El índice 1 es último índice del array simple.
- El índice 2 es el valor por el que se debe sustituir el elemento asociado al índice 0 del multidimensional.

El array simple sería algo como: [1, -2, 3, 4, -5, -4, 3, 2, 1] y el multidimensional: [[1, 3, 5], [0, 4, 2], [6, 8, 1]].

Por ponerlo más simple:
Dado el vector [1, -2, 3, 4, -5, -4, 3, 2, 1], según el primer rango del array multidimensional [1, 3, 5], se debería coger desde el valor -2 al 4, sustituir el -2 por el 5 en el proceso y sumarlos e ir acumulándolos en una variable, luego pasar al siguiente rango [0, 4, 2] y continuar.

Mi código es este:

```
let vector = [1, -2, 3, 4, -5, -4, 3, 2, 1];
let range = [[1, 3, 5], [0, 4, 2], [6, 8, 1]];

function getMaxValueByRange(vectors, ranMatrix) {
    var result = 0;

    Loop1:
    for(let x in ranMatrix) {
        let indx = ranMatrix[x][0];
        for(let i in vectors) {
            if(vectors.indexOf(vectors[i]) == indx) {
                let newRange = vectors.slice(indx, ranMatrix[x][1] + 1);
                newRange[0] = ranMatrix[x][2];
                result += newRange.reduce((total, num) => total + num, 0);
                continue Loop1;
            }
        } 
    }

    return result;
}

getMaxValueByRange(vector, range);
```

El código funciona bien en los dos primeros rangos del array multidimensional, pero, por alguna razón, con el [6, 8, 1] no entra en la condición. Lo he depurado y el valor es correcto, pero cuando llega al índice 6 del bucle lo ignora y sigue, y ni idea del por qué.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diría que no hace falta recorrer `vectors`, tenemos que:

- El valor en la posición `0` indica el índice "desde"
- El valor en la posición `1` indica el índice "hasta"

Entonces, podrías hacerlo así:

```js
let vector = [1, -2, 3, 4, -5, -4, 3, 2, 1];
let range = [[1, 3, 5],[0, 4, 2],[6, 8, 1]];

function getMaxValueByRange(vectors, ranMatrix) {
  var result = 0;

  for (let x in ranMatrix) {
    let newRange = vectors.slice(ranMatrix[x][0], ranMatrix[x][1] + 1);
    newRange[0] = ranMatrix[x][2];
    result += newRange.reduce((total, num) => total + num, 0);
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(getMaxValueByRange(vector, range));
```

---

La respuesta a la pregunta *"¿Por qué no entra en la condición si el valor es correcto?"* es:

`vectors.indexOf(vectors[i])` devuelve la posición en el arreglo del valor `vectors[i]`. Cuando `i = 6`, `vectors[i] = 3` y la posición de `3` en `vectors` es igual a `2` (*por que hay dos `3` en vectors*)

Comment: Muchas gracias. No lo había visto de esa forma; no hacían falta los bucles anidados ni la condición, pero no había caído en lo de que habían dos 3 en el vectors y por eso hacía aguas. Gracias otra vez.